# HTTP PUT file upload progress

Tags: php, javascript, rest, file-upload, http-put

I am currently experimenting with implementing RESTful APIs.

When using POST and the $_FILES system in PHP there are mechanisms for determining upload progress (using APC in older versions of PHP and [`session.upload_progress` in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/session.upload-progress.php)).

However, my searching of Google doesn't turn up any results for monitoring upload progress when using HTTP PUT to upload a file. As far as I can tell the above mechanisms don't work with PUT.

Is it possible to monitor upload progress when doing a HTTP PUT?  If so, how can it be done?

**ETA**: If there's a way of doing this entirely client-side in Javascript, that would be fine (it might actually be better, if it can avoid AJAX polling of the server whilst the upload is in progress).

Comment: PHP has no real support of PUT. You might want to look one step earlier what the server provides. See as well http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: If there's an entirely client-side solution that would be great.